# angular 4 issue with date format

Tags: angular

In my angular 2 application I need to show the below date in specific format but the date filter is not showing correctly.
Input :

```
let givenDate ="20170328"
```

I need to show this as Mar 28, 2017. As the input is just normal string, how can I achieve this?

Comment: use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a new pipe because the date string you above given is not normal date string format.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDate'
})
export class MyDate implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value) {
        let dateArray = value.split("");
        let year = dateArray[0]+dateArray[1]+dateArray[2]+dateArray[3];
        let month = dateArray[4]+dateArray[5];
        let date= dateArray[6]+dateArray[7];
        let dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
        return dateString;
    }
}
```

Then we got the return value as valid date format. And also you can return date from here as date string 
eg : `dateString.toDateString();` then return date format will be `Tue Mar 25 2017`

Otherwise you can simply return dateString as in the above code and in html put the date pipe, eg:

```
<div>{{givenDate | myDate | date:'DD/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
```